# How do I change the total price when the quantity changes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When the user enters the number of tickets they want in the text box, the subtotal should automatically change/update. What do I have to add to get this working?

```
<form id="confirmInfo" action="bookingsuccess.html">
  <p>Number of tickets :
    <input type="text" type="num" />
  </p>
  <p>Price Per ticket : $7</p>
  <p>Booking fee : $2</p>
  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b>
  </p>
  <form name="myform" action="bookingsuccess.php" method="post">
    <button>Book</button>
  </form>
  <button>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i know but what? like how do i even calculate it HAHAH

Comment: type="text" type="num". HTML tags can not have the same attribute name multiple times. Start from here if you plan to write code again: http://www.w3schools.com/js otherwise... wait for a good guy with free time to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of what you need. Please ask questions, if any, for explanations

```js
function calc() 
{
  var price = document.getElementById("ticket_price").innerHTML;
  var noTickets = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var total = parseFloat(price) * noTickets
  if (!isNaN(total))
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total
}
```

```html
<form id="confirmInfo" action="bookingsuccess.html">
  <p>Number of tickets :<input id="num" type="text" oninput="calc()" /> </p>
  <p>Price Per ticket : $<span id="ticket_price">7</span></p>
  <p>Booking fee : $2</p>
  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b></p>


  <form name="myform" action="bookingsuccess.php" method="post">
    <button>Book</button>
  </form>
  <button>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to take in consideration the booking fee. If you don't know how to do it, let me know and I will guide you. You can add it in the calculation as i've added the price (also a span tag will be required with an id) or you can add it directly in javascript, as a variable that is equal with the required booking fee, and use it in the sum.

Comment: thks! it worked. yup, i edited it to add the booking fee :)

Comment: when I am using this in a foreach loop ,it only working for the first element only. how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First it will make sense if you only allow numeric ,to do this you have to check every given character on `keydown` event and allow only desirable input like : numeric,Ctrl+c ...  : [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery#answer-995193).

Second, to get what you user wrote in this field and do your calculation, you can use `change();` or  `keyup();` event.

PS: you have to add a `class` or `id` attribute to your required element if you want to get its value.

#### JQuery solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tickets_number").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        
    });
    
    $(".tickets_number").keyup(function (e) {
       $('#total').html(($(this).val()*7)+2);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="confirmInfo" action="bookingsuccess.html">
          <p>Number of tickets :<input type="text" class="tickets_number" value=""/> </p>
              <p>Price Per ticket : $7</p>
              <p>Booking fee : $2</p>
              <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b></p>


              <form name="myform" action="bookingsuccess.php" method="post">
              <button>Book</button>
              </form>
              <button>Cancel</button>

          </form>
```

Comment: thks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

First add any id you prefer to `<input type="text" type="num" />` i suggest id="num_of_tickets" so your input field will be `<input id="num_of_tickets" type="text" type="num" />`
Secondly create use javascript onkeyup event so the final shape of your input will be like

```
<input id="num_of_tickets" onkeyup="calc()" type="text" type="num" />
```

this function will automatically trigger whenever there is value change in the input field
Third add this script to the head or footer to achieve desired result

```
<script>
function calc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num_of_tickets").value;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x * 7 + 2;
}
</script>
```

Here replace 7 and 2 as per requirement or use variables instead

NOTE: You are using form tags inside another form tags this is a wrong practice, use only one instead

Comment: thks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to keep as simple as possible using jQuery for number input you should use `<input type="number" />` then calculate the sub total with `$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function() {}`

```js
var perTicket = 7;
var bookingFee = 2;
var $subTotal = $('#total');

$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function() {
  if (!$(this).val().trim().length) return;
  var total = $(this).val() * perTicket + bookingFee;
  $subTotal.text(total);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="confirmInfo" action="bookingsuccess.html">
  <p>Number of tickets :
    <input type="number" />
  </p>
  <p>Price Per ticket : $7</p>
  <p>Booking fee : $2</p>
  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b>
  </p>
  <form name="myform" action="bookingsuccess.php" method="post">
    <button>Book</button>
  </form>
  <button>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thks for helping! :)

Answer (score -1):

Html Code

```
<form id="confirmInfo" action="bookingsuccess.html">
              <p>Number of tickets :<input type="text" type="num" id="tickets"/> </p>
                  <p>Price Per ticket : $7</p>
                  <p>Booking fee : $2</p>
                  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b></p>


                  <form name="myform" action="bookingsuccess.php" method="post">
                  <button>Book</button>
                  </form>
                  <button>Cancel</button>

              </form>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#tickets").change(function(){
        var numberOfTickets=parseInt( $(this).val());
        var total = (numberOfTickets * 7) + 2 ;
        $("#total").val(total);
});
})
```

Comment: thks for helping! :)